# Pandas: Where is the function for mean that ignores NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data frame on which I want to do some groupby-apply:

```
dftest = df1.append(test2).set_index('date')
doWhat = {'foo' : np.sum, 'bar': np.sum, 'employment_total' : np.mean}
```

`employment_total` is `NaN` at some places, but not everywhere:

```
>>> sum(np.isnan(dftest.employment_total))
404394
>>> sum(np.isnan(dftest.employment_total) == False)
6864
```

However, when I create monthly mean values, it will be `NaN` everywhere - I guess because I am using `np.mean`:

```
aggASS = dftest.groupby(['state', pd.TimeGrouper("M", label='left'), 'status']).agg(doWhat)
>>> aggASS.loc[np.isnan(aggASS.employment_total) == False]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [shopping_weighted, employment_total]
Index: []
```

I need to use `doWhat`, as I am using different measures of aggregation for the different columns. I tried to locate the `pandas.mean` function that removes `NaN` before computation, but I couldn't find it. Where is it?

Comment: You can use the pandas series version: `doWhat = {'foo' : np.sum, 'bar': np.sum, 'employment_total' : pd.Series.mean}` you may be able to get away with just `doWhat = {'foo' : np.sum, 'bar': np.sum, 'employment_total' : mean}` this has the `skipna` arg which by default is True so will skip `NaN` values

Comment: Also prefer the top level pandas `isnull` and `notnull` rather than numpy versions `sum(dftest.employment_total.isnull())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the mean argument as a string `'mean'` and it will use [the pandas version](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) which, by default, will skip nans.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, pd.np.nan], 'y':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']})

funcs = {'x':'mean'}

print(df.groupby('y').agg(funcs))
#    x
# y   
# a  2
# b  4
```